# Out of memory filtering an HDF5 table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have a 4+ Gb HDF5 table with rows corresponding to nodes in a tree-like structure. There are 3 salient columns: `name`, `surname`, `weight`. Surname logs the name of the parent of a given node, name is the name of the current node (relative to the parent), and weight is the weight of the node. The name and surname are both strings, and surname+name forms a unique identifier for this node. Finally, for any given node, the weight of its children are strictly smaller than its own weight.

My problem is that I want to filter this table to find all nodes whose weight is less than a given threshold value M, but if a node exists in my final set, its parent should not be in the set.

I have used `pd.read_hdf(,where = ['weight < M'])` to get all nodes less whose weight satisfies my condition, but I do not know how to satisfy the second half. This also needs to be done mostly out of memory, since the table itself is enormous.

EDIT: I've never asked a question on here before, so if you need more clarity, please ask

UPDATE: Here is a sample of the table.

```
surname    name    weight
1          1       0.016496
1          2       0.004884
1          3       0.004691
```

To clarify what I mean by `nodes`, imagine each row is represents properties of the lower 3 nodes in the following graph:

```
       1  
  /    |     \  
11     12     13  
...    ...    ...
```

The node 12 for example is named by taking the name of its parent (1), and concatenating its position (2)
The nodes 11, 12, and 13, each have 3 nodes as their children whose weights are strictly smaller than their respective parents. If I set the weight threshold M = 0.0165, I want to return the nodes 11, 12, and 13, without any of their children.

Comment: Could you post the whole piece of code, because it's not quite clear. And what do you mean saying `nodes`? What is `the second half`? It would be also pretty helpful if you would specify a sample data set (5-7 rows)

Comment: By second half, I meant I dont know how to satisfy the condition that if a node is in my final set, its parent is not. I hope my edit clarifies my situation a little further

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to find the first nodes where the weight drops below the threshold

Comment: for the node `111` - how do you distinguish whether it's `1+11` or `11+1`?

Comment: Every node has exactly 3 children, each named 1, 2, 3

Comment: so node 13 has the following children: 131,132,133?

Comment: Yes, exactly!
The reason for the slightly weird node naming is because after the filtering, I am performing operations on the table that depends on grouping nodes by their parent, so it became more useful to save the parent's name.

Comment: so all returned rows should have the same node length (for example 131,132,133, but not 1311,1312,etc.). But I guess you would have to provide more sample data and expected output, because it's still not quite clear. You data structure is very unusual and not very convenient for filtering

Comment: Try always to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions. In case of _pandas_ questions please provide sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format _as text_, so one could use it when coding an answer for you)

Comment: Not exactly. The selection process is by weight, so it may not be the case that all nodes have the same length. For example, look at it as a growing process:
The root has some initial weight larger than M, so we grow the tree in 3 directions.
Node 1 and 2 both have weight smaller than M, so we return them. However node 3 has weight larger than M, so we grow it. Node 131 has weight < M so we return it, but 132 and 133 have weight larger then M, so continue the growth process.

Comment: @MaxU I will try to make a better example. It's because this procedure is so unusual that I have trouble doing that.

Comment: Sorry, I'll have to do this at a later time. I shall return tomorrow

Comment: I ended up just creating node objects instead of using this table. It became too cumbersome using this structure wasn't working well. Thanks @MaxU

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a pandas like syntax and you have out of core requirements you will need something like Blaze to control it.  [The documentation](http://blaze.pydata.org) says that it can handle HDF5 files in the parallel processing section.

However your question as to what you want to do with it isn't clear.  Please give examples of data input and output if you must.